# How to pass parameters to SoapUI in command line?

Tags: groovy, command-line, soapui

SoapUI could be started from [command line with some set of parameters](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html):

```
testrunner.bat -FPDF -R"JUnit-Style HTML Report" -c"my test case" c:\my projects\my-project.xml
```

And it is stated that:

> **D** : Specifies a value of a system property for the test run. The
>   specified value will override the variable's value during the run.
>   Usage: `-D=`. If the value includes spaces, enclose the entire argument
>   in quotes. To override several variable values, specify the -D
>   argument several times.

So I tried to use:

```
... -Dusername=John
```

And get this parameter in the code of test case:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("username")
```

But the returned value is `null`. Any ideas how to pass parameters to SoapUI in command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter should be passed with `-P` param:

> **P** : Specifies a value of a project property for the test run. The
>   specified value will override the variable's value during the run.
>   Usage: `-P<variable>=<value>`. If the value includes spaces, enclose the
>   entire argument in quotes. To override several variable values,
>   specify the `-P` argument several times.

And

> **P** : Sets project property with *name=value*, e.g. *-Pendpoint=Value1 -PsomeOtherProperty=value2*

And get this parameter in the code of test case:

```
ep = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("endpoint") // ep = "Value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

-P works fine

sh testrunner.sh -Pproperty1=value1 -Pproperty2=value2